# Loop Wordpress Articles in Polymer

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, wordpress, polymer

i want to write an polymer element that displays some wordpress articles.
http://www.jsv-lippstadt.de/?json=get_category_posts&slug=app <- This is the Json File that contains all Posts.

My Code:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<polymer-element name="wordpress-post" attributes="from">
<template>
    <h1>Test</h1>
</template>

<script>
    Polymer('wordpress-post', {
        ready: function () {
            alert(this.from);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://www.jsv-lippstadt.de/?json=get_category_posts&slug=" + this.from,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                error: function () {
                    alert('Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed');
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var arr = $.map(data, function(el) { return el; })
                    console.log(arr);
                }
            });
        },
    })
</script>
```

This outputs a JavaScript Array. (console.log(arr)).

So how can i loop this array to display the Posts? I dont know how to make this in Polymer. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should setup an internal property called `posts` and then set it equal to the value of `arr` once it's returned by your ajax call. Then use [a repeat attribute on a template](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/template.html#repeat) to generate the posts.

ex:

```
<polymer-element name="x-foo">
  <template>
    <template repeat="{{post in posts}}">
      <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      created: function() {
        this.posts = [{title: 'hello'},{title: 'world'}];
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<x-foo></x-foo>
```

Comment: Nice and simple example. The solution should be obvious